# D3 selectAll gets more results than expected

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using `nvd3` `multiChart`, and I have a function that uses `$timeout` and then calculates and changes y-axis ticks attribute: `transform: translate(x, y)` y values. It works fine 90% of the times but sometimes (and consistently) `d3.selectAll` finds more "ticks" than expected. I look at the DOM and there are only 6 ticks, but `d3.selectAll` finds or 10 or 11 elements.

```
var selector = '#' + uid + ' .lineChart .nvd3 .nv-y1.nv-axis.nvd3-svg .nvd3.nv-wrap.nv-axis .tick';

var ticks = d3.selectAll(selector);
ticks.attr("transform", function (label, index) {
     return "translate(0," + (baseHeight / 5) * (ticks[0].length - index - 1) + ")"
});
```

`baseHeight` is the calculated height of the chart (calculated earlier and gives correct result).

Since `ticks[0].length` returns a different number than expected (there are always supposed to be 6 ticks - i'm using `tickValues` to set it by myself) calculations are wrong and chart is all messed up.

What am I doing wrong? any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you `console.log`ged the additional elements and located them? Maybe you add some ticks somewhere you don't expect them.

Comment: I tried to comapre logs of correct and wrong cases, but they all look the same (10 `<g>` tags with the same properties) and on the DOM there are only 6... maybe the timing is wrong, but even when `$timeout` is very long, it is still the same.

Comment: can  you add working example on plunker

Comment: You can show the exact location of the `<g>`s by right-clicking on it an displaying it inside the DOM tree to see *where* they are located

Comment: it looks like "old" `<g>` tags are still found somehow even though they were removed from DOM. is there a `d3.selectAll` only for currently existing DOM elements?